# React или Vue? С чего начать изучать реактивное программирование?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vue3

уважаемые коллеги!

Планирую изучить и освоить реактивное web-программирование и в качестве инструмента использовать для этого React либо Vue.

Но пока остановился перед выбором - с какого инструмента начать, чтобы фундаментально подойти к вопросу, понять концептуальные основы технологии, быстро разобраться в специфике построения архитектуры объектов и написания кода, а также, продвигаться от простого к сложному.

Данный вопрос в большей степени адресован специалистам с достаточным практическим опытом использования React или Vue, чтобы заметить разницу между фреймворками и дать аргументированные рекомендации на сей счёт.

Прошу присоединяться к беседе и выразить свою точку зрения на выше озвученный вопрос, с какого инструмента удобнее было бы начать освоение реактивного web-программирования?

Comment: Начинайте с любого, нарабатывайте багаж опыта и знаний.

Comment: Во Vue вроде порог входа по-ниже. Начинай с него.